Simple question regarding fraction to ratio conversions
Supposed you have a ratio expressed
in the form 4:8 . How do we convert this to fraction?
One answer gives me 1/2 in its simplest  form. Chatpt produces the same result
[enter image description here][1]
However  other sources says you have to add the entire part as a denominator, this will give the answer 4/12, which is 1/3 in its simplest form:
[enter image description here][2]
So which answer is correct?
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/nBvtoxPN.jpg
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/AJtnk7h8.jpg

This depends on context. If $4:8$ is part-to-whole, then that represents $\frac{1}{3}.$ If it's part-to-part, then it's $\frac{1}{2}.$

Actually this comment should be the answer. It really depends on context  as part of a larger problem

The context matters.
If I have a mixture that is 1 part of material A and 3 parts material B, then the ratio of material A to B is $1:3,$ but the fraction of material A to the whole mixture is $1:4.$ The first is a part-to-part ratio, and the second is part-to-whole. In this case, the part-to-part fraction is $\frac{1}{3},$ and the part-to-whole fraction is $\frac{1}{4}.$
Always observe the context.

They are correct answers to different questions.  You did not specify the question being asked.  If you are making salad dressing with four parts vinegar to eight parts oil you are using $\frac 48 =\frac 12$ as much vinegar as oil.  The vinegar constitutes $\frac 4{4+8}=\frac 4{12}=\frac 13$ of the total mix.

It wasn't a direct question but part of a larger question problem. If we know the context we are dealing with it becomes clearer and we can use the appropriate values. Using the wrong values will affect the final answer
